# Format string with values from column using pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Using Python 3, I'm trying to replace a certain word in a URL that I've put into a Dataframe with 732 rows of the same URL. This is the URL: `http://dbarchive.biosciencedbc.jp/kyushu-u/hg19/eachData/bed20/**ID**.bed`.

I have another Dataframe that contains 732 rows of different experimental IDs. I want to be able to replace the word 'ID' in the URL with each of the experimental IDs so that I get an updated Dataframe with every single one of the 732 URLs I need to download a .bed file into Python.

As a side note - from there, is it possible to download a .bed file into Python without having to first save it through my browser and then upload it into Python?

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` with `str.format`.

```
import random

# Setup
url = 'http://.../bed20/{}.bed' 

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.random.choice(100, 5).astype(str)})
```

```
df['ID'].map(url.format)

0    http://.../bed20/44.bed
1    http://.../bed20/47.bed
2    http://.../bed20/64.bed
3    http://.../bed20/67.bed
4    http://.../bed20/67.bed
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Replace with your own URL and ID dataframes.

---

Alternatively, use a list comprehension (should be around the same in terms of performance) ...

```
[url.format(x) for x in df['ID']]    
# ['http://.../bed20/44.bed', 
#  'http://.../bed20/47.bed', 
#  'http://.../bed20/64.bed', 
#  'http://.../bed20/67.bed', 
#  'http://.../bed20/67.bed']

df.assign(ID=[url.format(x) for x in df['ID']])

                        ID
0  http://.../bed20/44.bed
1  http://.../bed20/47.bed
2  http://.../bed20/64.bed
3  http://.../bed20/67.bed
4  http://.../bed20/67.bed
```

Comment: The actual experimental ID is made up of numbers and letters and can't be randomized. How do I do that?

Comment: @Lauren It works the same way no matter what IDs you have. I can't solve your problem for you because I don't have your data. But I've shown you how _you_ can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `apply` and `format`

```
fmt = 'http://dbarchive.biosciencedbc.jp/kyushu-u/hg19/eachData/bed20/{}.bed'
df.ID.apply(fmt.format)
```

Comment: How do I insert the IDs from my other dataframe though? Keeping in mind that there's 732 unique IDs so I have to create  732 unique URLs?